# "Error while fetching an original source" in new rails app (Sprockets 4, Firefox 70)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, sprockets, ruby-on-rails-6

It seems sprockets 4.0.0 is compatible with Chrome 78, but not Firefox 70.

Starting with a new rails app:

```
rails -v # Rails 6.0.0
rails new helloworld
```

```
# Gemfile
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 6' # not 5
```

```
bundle | grep sprockets
Using sprockets 4.0.0
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
```

```
# layouts/application.html.erb
javascript_include_tag 'application'
```

```
# app/assets/javascripts/application.js
console.log('line 1');
throw 'line 2';
```

```
# app/assets/config/manifest.js
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
```

```
# Dev tools console, Firefox 70
line 1 application.source.js:1
uncaught exception: line 2 application.source.js:2
Error while fetching an original source: "http://localhost:3000/assets/application.source.js" is not in the SourceMap.
Source URL: <unknown>
```

Works fine in Chrome 78

Comment: Can confirm failing in Firefox 70 and working in Chrome 78 using Sprokets. Is this Firefox or Sprockets causing the issue? Curious if Webpacker is experiencing any problems too.

Comment: Opened issue: https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/649

Comment: I confirm that I have same `Error while fetching an original source:` error in Firefox 73 (I can not even use `debugger` command in any javascript file since it does not see the source), but it works in Chrome 81.

Comment: Same here with Firefox 73.